# Echo of String with Double Quotes to Output file using Windows Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm attempting to rewrite a configuration file using a Windows Batch file.
I'm looping through the lines of the file and looking for the line that I want to replace with a specified new line.

I have a 'function' that writes the line to the file

```
:AddText %1 %2
set Text=%~1%
set NewLine=%~2%
echo "%Text%" | findstr /C:"%markerstr%" 1>nul
if errorlevel 1 (
  if not "%Text%" == "" (
      setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
      (
          echo !Text!
      ) >> outfile.txt
  ) else (
     echo. >> outfile.txt
  )
) else (
  set NewLine=%NewLine"=%
  setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
  (
      echo !NewLine!
  ) >> outfile.txt

)
exit /b
```

The problem is when %Text% is a string with embedded double quotes.
Then it fails.  Possibly there are other characters that would cause it to fail too.
How can I get this to be able to work with all text found in the configuration file?

Comment: If you want it to work reliably, don't use batch - use powershell or vbscript, or another scripting language.

Comment: That would be great, but I really don't have that as an option.

Comment: Actually the problem seems to be which double quotes embedded in the echo here:  echo %Text% | findstr /C:"%markerstr%" 1>nul

Comment: It expands to something like:  echo #blah blah on "AS | findstr /C:"blah"  -- The double quotes causes problems

Comment: Using delayed expansion will solve that particular problem, I think.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try replacing all `"` in `Text` with `^"`.

`^` is escape character so the the `"` will be treated as regular character

you can try the following:

```
:AddText %1 %2
set _Text=%~1%
set Text=%_Text:"=^^^"%

... rest of your code

REM for example if %1 is "blah"blah"blah"
REM _Text will be blah"blah"blah
REM Text will be blah^"blah^"blah
```

Other characters that could cause you errors (you can solve it with the above solution) are:

```
\ & | > < ^
```

Comment: Parenthesis also cause issues.

Answer (score 3):

In a windows batch shell (command) double quote are escape with `^` on standard command line BUT with a double double quote inside a double quoted string

```
echo Hello ^"Boy^"
echo "Hello ""Boy"""
```

(remark: second line will produce the external surrounding double quote in the output also)